# Is there a bijection between infinite-dimensional linear spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces and $f: V \to W$ be a linear map.

I know that if both $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional and $\rm{dim}(V)=\rm{dim}(W)$, then $f$ is surjective $\iff$ $f$ is injective owing to the rank–nullity theorem.
But, the equivalence relation also holds when both $V$ and $W$ are infinite-dimensional?

I'm writing proof for this problem, but I'm at a loss.

Comment: It is not true that $f$ is bijective in general, even in (equal) finite dimensions

Comment: Did you mean to assume that $f$ is *one to one* as well?

Comment: I wrote the false statement. I'm sorry.

Comment: Let $k$ be a field. The linear map $R \colon k^\mathbb N \to k^\mathbb N$ given by $R(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots) = (0,x_1,x_2,\dots)$ is injective but not surjective. The linear map $L \colon k^\mathbb N \to k^\mathbb N$ given by $L(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots) = (x_2,x_3,x_4,\dots)$ is surjective but not injective.

Comment: No, it is not true for infinite-dimensional

Comment: An example of countable dimension is $k[x]$ of polynomials. Then the map $f(x)\mapsto xf(x)$ is one-to-one, but not onto. In reverse, $f(x)\mapsto \frac{f(x)-f(0)}x$ is onto, but not one-to-one.

Comment: Thanks for your help!